# How to conveniently restart pgAdmin 4?

Tags: bash, catalina, dock, postgresql

I have pgAdmin on my dock, and can open it when the process isn't already running (ie. after a restart, or if I manually kill it).

If I open pgAdmin, close the window, then later try to open it from the dock, the app doesn't respond.

This dock behavior is similar to *MySQL Workbench*, **except** that *MySQL* has the *"running process indicator"* (little circle on dock below the icon), while pgAdmin **does not**, which means that right clicking on the pgAdmin icon does not give me the option to quit.

I tried using a bash function, which for MySQL would look like this:

```
killall MySQLWorkbench && open /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app
```

This works fine for *MySQL Workbench*, but isn't necessary since I can restart it from the dock.

For some reason, with pgAdmin, the process doesn't get killed, so the app never opens:

```
>> killall pgAdmin\ 4
No matching processes were found
```

The app is clearly visible in Activity Monitor with the name **`pgAdmin 4`**

The only solution I have currently is to manually kill the process from Activity Monitor, but this is quite redundant.

> How can I *conveniently* restart **pgAdmin 4**?

I would prefer a solution that allows me to restart it from the dock, but a bash script would also suffice.

Software:

- *pgAdmin 4* : **4.17**
- *macOS Catalina* : **10.15**

Comment: @klanomath Thanks, but I didn't quite get that last part.  What did you mean *"task makes no sense"* ?

Comment: @klanomath don't be sorry, they were helpful!  thanks

Comment: @klanomath Also, I needed the bash script because if the browser process ends while pgAdmin is running, then any attempts to go `http://127.0.0.1:63145/browser/` will result in an authorization error, which I think is a bug/design flaw.

Comment: not to forget: I was tired (it was 3am in the morning) and I couldn't really believe that|understand why pgAdmin not only shut down itself but also the PostgreSQL server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*pgAdmin 4* (/Applications/PostgreSQL 12/pgAdmin 4.app) is a simple launcher for /Library/PostgreSQL/12/pgAdmin 4.app which itself is some kind of a service wrapper.

Besides launching a small web server, it also starts the menulet "pgAdmin 4" (the black elephant) and probably does some other things too.

The recommended way to restart pgAdmin 4 is to quit the menulet pgAdmin 4 ("Shut down server") and launch pgAdmin 4 again from the Dock.

If you insist to use the shell or a shell script, the best you can get is probably something like:

```
kill -s TERM $(ps aux | grep '[p]gAdmin4' | awk '{print $2 }') && open -a "pgAdmin 4"
```

You have to clean up (i.e. close) the now defunct browser window of the previous session manually.

---

If you just want to re-visit the pgAdmin PostgreSQL management page (after accidentally exiting the browser or closing the browser window/tab or if you want to use another browser) you don't have to quit and relaunch pgAdmin.

The formerly displayed url (e.g. *http://127.0.0.1:49211/browser/*) won't work anymore but a file in your home folder contains a working url with an auth key:

```
cat ~/.pgA*.addr
http://127.0.0.1:49211/?key=c1b4f6c8-fa99-4af2-9ebd-06d71586c266 #example
```

Enter this url in your browser and you can visit the page without authorization error .

In the shell this is: `open $(cat .pgA*.addr)`. This will launch your standard web browser and open the management page.